# How to position text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]I am new to JS and is looking for a way to set the position for a text for a html website.

My codes are.

```js
function changeText(value) {
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  var text = "";
  var image = "";

  if (value == 1) text += "this is picture one <br> <img class='custom_h_w'  src='images/consumers_1.png'/>";
  if (value == 2) text += "this is picture two <br> <img class='custom_h_w'  src='images/consumers_2.png'/>";
  if (value == 3) text += "this is picture tree <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='images/consumers_3.png'/>";

  div.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: changeText(1);">
   <img id="searchconsumers" src="images/search.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(2);">
   <img id="exploreconsumers" src="images/explore.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(3);">
   <img id="funconsumers" src="images/fun.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: You will want to use CSS to position your elements. Can you give us an example of how you want to position it?

Comment: style your `custom_h_w` class

Comment: Hi Cory, thanks for your reply. Yes CSS will be my solution. I want to position it not in the center but a little to the right. Can I make a top and right as in html?

Comment: my custom_h_w class is for a picture

Comment: You are very unclear on what goal you are trying to achieve. Positioning text (layout) is usually in the purvey of CSS, so why mention JS at all? Give us a clearer idea of what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: JS is because I click an image and a text and a new image is showing up. 
The new image showing up is positioned using CSS. So now I want to position the text

Comment: You said you want it a little to the right. Have you tried adding `padding-left` to the `div` ID?

Comment: Seperate your thinking, layout and position is very unrelated to how interactions works - they work better decoupled. Use CSS to lay things out, use JS to let your click do something (but not style something! Use CSS and classes for that)

Comment: That didn't work. I think the problem is that I don't know how to get it from JS to CSS. In order to position a image I called a img class in js and got i to CSS that way. Can I calla text class in JS?

Comment: The text is not the element you want to position, the element is the `<div id="div">` where you added your text to

Comment: Thanks somethinghere. I do have  "click to do something" and thats why I use js. I click a image and a text and new image show up. In order to position the new image showing up I call a "img class" in js. So can I also call a "text class" ?

Comment: Add CSS to your `<div id="div">` element and add something like `padding-left: 20px;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to wrap your text by a `span` then create a new class using your text position rules, it'll be something like the following example.

Hope this helps.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  document.querySelector('#p_1').click();
})

function changeText(value) {
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  var text = "";
  var image = "";

  if (value == 1) text += "<span class='custom_text_h_w'>this is picture one</span> <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='http://www.xerys.com/images/xerys/1.png'/>";
  if (value == 2) text += "<span class='custom_text_h_w'>this is picture two</span> <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='http://www.xerys.com/images/xerys/2.png'/>";
  if (value == 3) text += "<span class='custom_text_h_w'>this is picture tree</span> <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='http://www.xerys.com/images/xerys/3.png'/>";

  div.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
.custom_h_w{
  top: 120px;
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.custom_text_h_w{
  top: 70px;
  right: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: changeText(1);" id="p_1">
   <img id="searchconsumers" src="images/search.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(2);" id="p_2">
   <img id="exploreconsumers" src="images/explore.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(3);" id="p_3">
   <img id="funconsumers" src="images/fun.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can also be so kind to help me with this: I have added a picture for clarification. When I click on button 1 a picture will show up to the left and a text will show up in the middle. if I click on button 2 a new picture will show up to the left and a new text will show up in the middle. 
But how do I as default show picture 1 and text one when the website is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using CSS for your positioning. I suggest you learn about the [CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) to give you a better understanding of how layout works with CSS.

Say for example, you had 3 elements. You could position in the center and offset in one direction in this way:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
}

.middle {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">Div 1</div>
  <div class="child middle">Div 2</div>
  <div class="child">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, you want to push the text resulting from your JS slightly to the right. If you don't want the image to be pushed right, wrap your text in `<p>` or `<span>` tags and target those.

```js
function changeText(value) {
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  var text = "";
  var image = "";

  if (value == 1) text += "<p>this is picture one</p> <br> <img class='custom_h_w'  src='images/consumers_1.png'/>";
  if (value == 2) text += "<p>this is picture two</p> <br> <img class='custom_h_w'  src='images/consumers_2.png'/>";
  if (value == 3) text += "<p>this is picture tree</p> <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='images/consumers_3.png'/>";

  div.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
#div p {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: changeText(1);">
   <img id="searchconsumers" src="images/search.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(2);">
   <img id="exploreconsumers" src="images/explore.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(3);">
   <img id="funconsumers" src="images/fun.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can give position to element like

```
div.innerHTML = text;
    div.style.position = "absolute";
```

Comment: Thats literally _giving_ position, but not actually positioning anything...